# Get the Height and Width of a jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery UI Datepicker widget.  When the user changes the month or year on the widget my code makes an ajax request to the server to get the highlighted dates for that month/year.  In order to give the user an indication that the webpage is waiting for the server I'm trying to grey out the datepicker and display a loading image.  I can already do all of this, except, I'm having problems getting the height and width of the greyed out section to match the height and width of the datepicker widget.

Because the datepicker's height can change based on the number of weeks in a month each time I called the overlay I was trying to use jQuery to get the height of the widget and then display the overlay.  However, the height never seems to match the actual height of the datepicker.  Here are the two ways I've tried setting the height.

```
$('#loading').height($('.ui-datepicker-calendar').height() + $('.ui-datepicker-header').height())
```

and

```
$('#loading').height($('.ui-datepicker-inline.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all').height())
```

Neither of which work.  Does anyone know a way I can programmatically get the height and width of a jQuery UI Datepicker widget?

Comment: tried to use `var`s with `.outerHeight()` or `.outerHeight(true)`? And than something like: `$('#loading').height( dP_cal + dP_hea );`

Comment: First, I think you want spaces before each `.` class selector (I think?). Second, if you know for sure that's the right element to select for the height, have you tried [`.outerHeight(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)?

Comment: @Jared I _think_ not having spaces is OK in this case - jQuery UI puts a lot of classes on the same element.

Comment: @JamWaffles - So if the space is omitted and classes chained, that will select an element with all of those classes? (Never seen that before.)

Comment: @Jared That is correct. There's a link [here](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/multiple-classes/) that explains things. I'd look it up in the spec, but I don't like the thought of emerging on the other side with a beard and glasses ;-)

Comment: @JamWaffles - As I typed it, I wasn't sure, so thanks for clearing that up. `:)` And I don't know, maybe a beard and glasses would work for you. `:P`

Comment: @JamWaffles - (Off-topic Chronicles Vol. III, Sunday Edition) I'm well old enough to grow one but since I can't (I look very scruffy and big patches don't grow in), I would just say, "... one day..."

Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot as I can't tell exactly what you mean by `the height never seems to match the actual height`, other than it's not covering the whole datepicker. A solution to this may be [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) and [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/). These functions get the width of the element *including* border, padding and (optionally) margins:

```
$('#loading').height($('.ui-datepicker-calendar').outerHeight(false) + $('.ui-datepicker-header').outerHeight(false))

$('#loading').height($('.ui-datepicker-inline.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all').outerHeight(false))
```

`outerHeight(false)` means "get the height plus padding and border, but leave out the margin". Set it to `true` if you want to include the margin too.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work.  My problem is the overlay is too large. Here are the results I get from each height method. height() 194px, outerHeight() 198px (both false and true), innerHeight() 196px (both false and true). However, by playing with the console I find the height to be closer to 120px. I got the selectors I used in my example code by using firebug's inspect element. When I mouse over that element in the code the highlighted section on the page perfectly matches the widget height.  Yet, for some reason I can't seem to get that height with jQuery.

Comment: Well, I nor anyone else can suggest anything else if you don't give us some code, examples or screenshots to work with. Try changing your CSS selectors to find elements inside the containing `div` or something.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I wasn't aware of the `innerHeight()` and `outerHeight()` functions.  However, the problem was someone edited the file and added padding to the css class without my knowledge.

Comment: Yep, I posted my fix above.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`height()` works fine, the problem was that someone else had edited the file and added padding without my knowledge.  So when I set the height it always had a bunch of extra pixels added, making my overlay too large for the datepicker widget.  In addition it is sufficient to select `.ui-datepicker-inline`.  So my final jQuery code is:

```
$('#loading').height($('.ui-datepicker-inline').height());
```